# Is it possible to read the very first value of the JSON response

Tags: json

Here is a JSON response I am receiving from a server:

```
{
    "GoUZm0F3r-rZ0tItdurVfPLCAfBGrnvF32": {
        "entityId": "GoUZm0F3r-rZ0tItdurVfPLCAfBGrnvF32",
        "mergePolicy": {
            "id": "02596943-2bb0-497f-815c-ffc69bf4b9c0"
        }
    }
}
```

The value "GoUZm0F3r-rZ0tItdurVfPLCAfBGrnvF32" always changes with new response. Is it possible I can access this value dynamically to reuse it in my next API call?

Comment: Add more information to the question on exactly what you're doing, disqualifying a perfectly good answer like the one below after the fact is very bad form and could have been avoided if you had provided more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract it with `jq`

```
jq -r 'keys | .[0]'
```

Comment: Or `keys | first` if you want to avoid using array indexing syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use jq as I am using a server side application.

Comment: @Ashish What does that mean and how are we to know what tool you have access to? Please update your question.

Comment: @Ashish please at least indicate the language your server side application is written in.  (however, this may be more a computer language question than a Unix or Linux specific question)

Comment: "_Sorry, I can't use jq as I am using a server side application_" - in that case the only answer that can be given is "possibly". There is no information in your question to provide a better answer than that, @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is able to convert between several common structured formats, we can get it to read the JSON input, relabel the unfortunately labelled key into just `key`, flatten the data and pull out the `key.entityId` field's value.   The output is in "NIDX" (index-numbered (toolkit style)) format which is header-less and suits this application.

```bash
$ mlr --j2n label key then flatten then cut -f key.entityId file.json
GoUZm0F3r-rZ0tItdurVfPLCAfBGrnvF32
```

The `--j2n` option is a shorthand for `--ijson` (input JSON) together with `--onidx` (output NIDX).

Approximately the same operation using [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) (a very common JSON processor):

```bash
$ jq -r '.[].entityId' file.json
GoUZm0F3r-rZ0tItdurVfPLCAfBGrnvF32
```

In both these commands, we don't really care about the top-level key and instead go for the value of the `entityId` key in the inner structure.  JSON documents should generally store data in values, not in keys.  If they don't, it's a good sign they should have used an array instead.